# Why I can't drag outlets from a custom UIView Class?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a `TableViewController` With a `dynamic cell` and a view I added above it.
I've created a `UIView` class and added it as a custom class for that view ( just like I do with a `custom cell`) but I can't drag labels etc from that `UIView` to its `.h file`. Only to the main `TableViewController.h` file. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: u r using storyboard or interface builder?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using both :\

Comment: so I think you r using storyboard. but can u edit your question with more information like file name and how you have create custom cell and how you add uiview in cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table view in a UITableViewController takes up the whole screen, so the view you added is actually in the table view, not above it, so that's why you can connect to the table view controller. If you want to add a view above the table, use a UIViewController instead, and resize the table view so it doesn't take up the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this too (for an OS X project) in Interface Builder. I'm not sure if it is a bug or not in IB.

What you will have to do is enter the `@property` declarations in your `.h` file manually and then you will be able to connect them.

Comment: That's weird. I tried that too. The outlets are not recognized.

Comment: Where are you dragging the connections? To the view in IB or to the .h file?

Comment: after i write the property there's that circle next to each property. I've tried dragging from it to the view and from the view to it